# WinForm Controls behave differently on .Enabled = false

Tags: .net, winforms, controls

I have some controls on a WinForm namely: CheckedListBox, ListBox,ListView, TreeView, TextBox.

On

```
ControlName.Enabled = false;
```

I have found following results:

- ListView and TextBox's BackColor get greyed.
- CheckedListBox, ListBox and,TreeView's BackColor does not get greyed.

Why is this behavor? Is it a intented or Bug? and how to unify behavior?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, this is by design unless you override the default behavior.

This is not exactly related but I thought I will post a link to another question.

[How do I make a Windows Forms control readonly ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255955/how-do-i-make-a-windows-forms-control-readonly)